# curl command error - URL using bad/illegal format

Tags: docker, shell, curl, message, mailgun

when i run this command :

```bash
curl --user "api:$MAILGUN_API_KEY" 
      "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/$MAILGUN_DOMAIN/messages"
```

i am getting attached error , the api key and domain i have verified .Can you please help?

Comment: You don't seem to have actually included the error.  What's gone wrong?  Is there any application code relevant to this, or are you just trying to use a command-line tool to invoke an external API?

Comment: I have a feeling it has to do with the $MAILGUN_DOMAIN variable since it says URL using bad/illegal format. What is the value of that variable? Have you tried manually putting in the url without the variable? [About the error](https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/4408819734426-API-error-curl-3-URL-using-bad-illegal-format-or-missing-URL)